# Conditional Logic react native "Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component."

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

Hi i am making an app in react native and i have a problem

```
    let currentUserUID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    const [partnership, setPartnership] = useState('');
  
    useEffect(() => {
      async function getUserInfo(){
        let doc = await firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('users')
        .doc(currentUserUID)
        .get();
          let dataObj = doc.data();
          setPartnership(dataObj.partnership)
      }
      getUserInfo();
    })

    console.log(partnership)

    return(
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            {partnership === "Partner" || "1KPartner" || "BusinessPartner" &&
                <Text>You have permission</Text>
            }
            <LessonHeader navigation={navigation}/>
            <StyledBoxV3 style={{flex: 1}}>
                <LessonMenu item={item} navigation={navigation} />
            </StyledBoxV3>
        </View>
    )
};

const StyledBoxV3 = styled(StyledBox)`
    padding: 0;
    border-top-left-radius:0;
    border-top-right-radius:0 ;
`
```

so when someone is Partner, 1KPartner or BusinessPartner i want to show or hide specific data but i get the error

"Error: Text strings must be rendered within a  component."

The problem is in de conditional logic, if i delete it i dont have any problem. How can i make this work? I already tried to put a variable in my return and update it with a function in my useEffect but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Where are your imports? You should be importing { Text } from 'react-native'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic where you are comparing the value of the partnership is written wrong. I would suggest being classy and writing

```
{(partnership === "Partner" || 
  partnership === "1KPartner" || 
  partnership === "BusinessPartner") && 
  <Text>You have permission</Text>}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the condition like this,

A helper function to determine the component to render based on the `partnership` state.

```
  const renderPermissionText = (value: String) => {
    switch (value) {
      case 'Partner':
      case '1KPartner':
      case 'BusinessPartner':
        return <Text>You have permission</Text>;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  };
```

Update the Layout to

```
...
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  {renderPermissionText(partnership)}
  ...
</View>
```